# Unitary Matrix and Orthonormal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal, isometry

This is an exercise from Tapp's book. I have my solution, but I am not sure.

> Let $U: X\rightarrow X$  be a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional inner product space.
>
> True or False:
> Any Unitary matrix corresponds to a unit circle on an orthonormal basis.

Comment: You can write every vector $v \in X$ in the form $$v = a_1e_1 + \ldots + a_n e_n.$$ Using Pythagoras's theorem should establish $U$ as an isometry.

Comment: @TheoBendit Which Pythagoras' theorem are you referring to? $a^2+b^2=c^2$? I got two answers saying $U$ needs not be an isometry.

Comment: @Vivan L., Sorry, they're right. I read more into it, specifically that $(Ue_i)$ was orthonormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. You cannot jump from$$(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):\langle U^*Ue_k,e_k\rangle=\langle\operatorname{Id}_ne_k,e_k\rangle\tag1$$to $U^*U=\operatorname{Id}_n$. For instance, if $f\colon\mathbb{C}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ is defined by $f(x,y)=(x+y,0)$, then $(1)$ also holds, but $f\neq\operatorname{Id}_2$.

This example also shows that the statement is false.

Comment: @VivianL. That's another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: @VivianL. And you already got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false, as demonstrated by the example: $n = 2$ and $U(a e_1 + b e_2) = (a + b) e_1$.